# Align UIButton and UILabel text with different font sizes

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout, uilabel

I have a `UIButton` and a `UILabel` displayed inline. They have different size fonts, however I would like to align them so they appear on the same line.

At the moment the `UILabel` is slight above the baseline of the `UIButton`.

I was hoping to avoid manually setting a content offset as I want this to scale correctly where possible. I worry manual calculations may have unexpected side effects on changing font sizes etc.

[image: not aligned elements]

I have created a playground that should show the 2 elements:

```swift
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

  lazy var nameButton = configure(UIButton(type: .system), using: {
    $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    $0.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18)
    $0.setTitleColor(.darkGray, for: .normal)
    $0.contentHorizontalAlignment = .leading
    $0.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
    $0.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    $0.setTitle("This is a button", for: .normal)
  })

  lazy var publishedDateLabel = configure(UILabel(frame: .zero), using: {
    $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    $0.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    $0.textColor = .darkGray
    $0.setContentHuggingPriority(UILayoutPriority.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    $0.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    $0.text = "and this is a label"
  })

  override func loadView() {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    [nameButton, publishedDateLabel].forEach(view.addSubview(_:))

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      nameButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
      nameButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),

      publishedDateLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
      publishedDateLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameButton.trailingAnchor),
      publishedDateLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -8)
    ])

    self.view = view
  }

  // setup helper method
  func configure<T>(_ value: T, using closure: (inout T) throws -> Void) rethrows -> T {
    var value = value
    try closure(&value)
    return value
  }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

I have tried making the label and button the same height by adding `publishedDateLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameButton.heightAnchor)`

This didn't change the alignment however.

I also tried using `publishedDateLabel.lastBaselineAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameButton.lastBaselineAnchor)`
 to align the anchors however this aligned the top of the elements

[image: using bassline]

How can align the bottom of the text in the button to the bottom of the text in the label?

Comment: How do you want to look the label and button? what alignment you need to show?

Comment: I'd like the bottom text of each element to be aligned, so the bottom of the n in `button` just align with the bottom of the a in `and`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just comment out the `heightAnchor` use the `lastBaselineAnchor`:

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      nameButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
      nameButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),

      publishedDateLabel.lastBaselineAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameButton.lastBaselineAnchor),
      publishedDateLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nameButton.trailingAnchor),
      publishedDateLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -8)
    ])
```

[image: Live playground view]